# How do I insert something at a specific character with Regex in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string `"foo?bar"` and I want to insert `"baz"` at the `?`. This `?` may not always be at the 3 index, so I always want to insert something string at this `?` char to get `"foo?bazbar"`

Comment: Why do you need a regular expression for this? Just use the normal string replacement function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `String.protype.replace` method is perfect for this.

Example

```
let result = "foo?bar".replace(/\?/, '?baz');
alert(result);
```

I have used a RegEx in this example as requested, although you could do it without RegEx too.

Additional notes.

1. If you expect the string `"foo?bar?boo"` to result in `"foo?bazbar?boo"` the above code works as-is
2. If you expect the string `"foo?bar?boo"` to result in `"foo?bazbar?bazboo"` you can change the call to `.replace(/\?/g, '?baz')`

Answer (score -1):

You don't need a regular expression, since you're not matching a pattern, just ordinary string replacement.

```js
string = 'foo?bar';
newString = string.replace('?', '?baz');
console.log(newString);
```